# How to solve "Failed to calculate the value of task ':compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'" when building the default "hello world"gradle project

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm new to kotlin,gradle,java and idea. I'm running IDEA 2023.2.5 on Windows 10. The java version is shown below

```
C:\Users\Administrator>java -version
java version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The gradle project I created is the default "Hello world" project. However, when I try to build it, the error msgs are shown below:

```
Failed to calculate the value of task ':compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
Unable to download toolchain matching the requirements ({languageVersion=8, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}) from 'https://api.foojay.io/disco/v3.0/ids/99916d5878e922e25b4f443774d694e6/redirect'.
Could not HEAD 'https://github.com/adoptium/temurin8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u402-b06/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u402b06.zip'.
Connect to github.com:443 [github.com/20.205.243.166] failed: Connection timed out: no further information
Connection timed out: no further information
```

The first two links in the msgs are available when I try to download the zip file in manual.

But `github.com/20.205.243.166` is not available and shows "Not Found"

I also checked the build.gradle.kts whose contents are shown below:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.22"
    application
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(8)
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
```

I tried to change `jvmToolchain(8)` to `jvmToolchain(11)` but the problem is just the same.
So what should I check or change now?

Comment: If your JVM Major Version is 17, you should probably also use `jvmToolchain(17)` instead of 11. Also take a look at [this IntelliJ Support Issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11237218970642-How-to-fix-all-files-excluded-from-the-project-because-of-Failed-to-calculate-the-value-of-task-compileJava-error), it may give you additional pointers since the resulting error message in this issue looks similar. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Till Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4292075/till-kuhn) whose [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905752/how-to-solve-failed-to-calculate-the-value-of-task-compilejava-property-jav/77911199#comment137347607_77905752):

> If your JVM Major Version is 17, you should probably also use `jvmToolchain(17)` instead of 11. Also take a look at this IntelliJ Support Issue, it may give you additional pointers since the resulting error message in this issue looks similar. Good luck!

provided the answer - it worked when I used `jvmToolchain(17)`.